# Requesting all local ip devices ('ip neighbor')

Tags: sockets, ip

To detect all device on a wlan I tried to use 'ip neighbor'.
I was happy to see all known devices (compared what the fritz.box router also knows).
But suddenly I only get the server and one other device.

From a blog post I understood 'ip' command sometimes doesn't return all possible ip's. 
Is there a "force" call/command to get it back to verbose as before?